# Maintain orientation when resizing image with opencv

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

FYI, I'm new to OpenCV.  I'm creating an AWS Lambda function that will utilize OpenCV 2.4 to resize images that I have in S3.  S3 generates an event that launches my Lambda function when an image is uploaded to my source bucket.  The lambda function successfully resizes the images and stores the resized image to the target bucket with the same object key as the original image.  I have test images that where taken with a digital camera and some from an Android phone.  What I've noticed is if I have an image from the phone that was taken in portrait the image in the source bucket is oriented correctly but the resized version in the target bucket is orientated incorrectly.  Images taken in portrait orientation are converted to landscape.  How do I maintain the orientation when resizing images.  Below is the code I'm using.

```
    public Object handleRequest(S3Event input, Context context) {

    OpenCV.loadLibrary();

    for (S3EventNotificationRecord record : input.getRecords()) {

        String bucketName = record.getS3().getBucket().getName();
        S3ObjectEntity entity = record.getS3().getObject();

        String objectKey = entity.getUrlDecodedKey();
        context.getLogger().log("ObjectKey: " + objectKey);
        String fileExtension = objectKey.substring(objectKey.lastIndexOf("."));
        context.getLogger().log("file extension: " + fileExtension);
        S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, objectKey));
        InputStream objectData = object.getObjectContent();

        ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = object.getObjectMetadata();

        // Process the objectData stream.
        int nRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[16 * 1024];
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            while ((nRead = objectData.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                buffer.write(data, 0, nRead);
            }

            byte[] bytes = buffer.toByteArray();

            Mat srcImage = Highgui.imdecode(new MatOfByte(bytes), Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

            Mat resizedImage = new Mat();
            Imgproc.resize(srcImage, resizedImage, new Size(0,0), 0.1, 0.1, Imgproc.INTER_AREA);

            MatOfByte resizedMatOfByte = new MatOfByte();

            Highgui.imencode(fileExtension, resizedImage, resizedMatOfByte);

            byte[] bytesToWrite = resizedMatOfByte.toArray();
            ObjectMetadata meta = new ObjectMetadata();

            meta.setContentLength(bytesToWrite.length);
            meta.setContentType(objectMetadata.getContentType());

            PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest(Configuration.MINIMIZED_ARTIFACT_BUCKET, objectKey, new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesToWrite), meta);
            s3Client.putObject(putRequest);
            objectData.close();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return null;

}
```

Comment: Aren't you just losing some metadata in the process? (such as the EXIF orientation flag)

Comment: Yes, I believe that is true.  Although, I'm not sure how to extract this information from the source image and transfer it to the resized image.  I'm probably missing something simple but I'm not seeing an option for it.  Is there a simple way to do this with OpenCV when performing a resize?

Comment: I think OpenCV won't help here. Find some library that can parse the metadata from a stream or byte array and just transform (rotate and/or mirror) `srcImage` based on the orientation flag. Or if you find a library that can write the metadata as well, then instead of doing the rotations just restore the flag in `bytesToWrite`.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I've decided to use Python and Pillow for this.  I've been able to determine the orientation with Pillow and then I have to rotate the image accordingly.